# Prevent Pull Request builds from triggering Continuous deployment trigger Azure DevOps Server

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

## TL;DR

We want to prevent Pull Request branch policy builds in Azure Devops from triggering releases via the `Continuous deployment trigger` mechanism.

## Problem

We are currently users of Azure DevOps Server 2019 Version Dev17.M153.3

We are utilizing both Build and Release pipelines. When a user submits a Pull Request, we have a `Branch Policy` that queues a build to ensure that code compiles and any tests pass. The completion of this build triggers the `Continuous deployment trigger` we have configured on the Build artifact of the corresponding release - this is NOT ideal behavior for us.

Our ideal behavior is to have the Branch Policy build queued by a Pull Request NOT trigger the `Continuous deployment trigger` and therefore NOT queue a release. We only want to trigger a release via the `Continuous deployment trigger` if we MANUALLY queue a build. We never want this to happen with a branch policy build on a `Pull Request`.

We've tried using the `Build branch filters` in the `Continuous deployment trigger`, but have had no luck. I've tried setting this using `Exclude` and setting `Build branch` to `pull/*`, `refs/pull/*` and `merge` but have not had any luck with these filters, the release is still being queued.

I want to know if there is potentially a better way to handle this scenario, or if additional filters can be added to the `Continuous deployment trigger` to mitigate unwanted releases from being queued.

Comment: Based on my understand, what you want is no matter the PR is merging or merge finished, you all hope CD could not be triggered. (Correct me if I have any misunderstand). If this, I'm afraid the work around you are using and @Shamrai's answer would be the best choices for you, though these would be little complex or bring another trouble. Because CD means continues deployment which would be run **once source has any update**.

Comment: @MerlinLiang-MSFT hey Merlin. Thanks for chiming in. Yes I believe you have it correctly. When a PR is created or updated, a build is triggered via branch policy and we don’t want to CD that build. Thanks for your input. I will look into potentially setting up special builds for pull requests.

Comment: @Zam I know it's been a while, but I was just working on this myself and for whatever reason `refs/pull/*` worked as a build branch filter on the release. I just added it to the artifact's continuous deployment trigger. It may be something that works now but didn't before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We've established that there is no "best solution" for this problem at the moment, below are some alternatives.

## Easy work arounds

- Unlink your current PR Policy build definition from release definition and create new build definition (or clone exiting). Link this new build definition to your releases and run it manually.
- Remove Continuous deployment from your release definition and create your releases manually from your completed builds.
- Use continues deployment and set it to some branch. Then your deployment will trigger only after completing of PR (if you set CI for your build).

[image]

---

## Release variables and custom conditions (single artifact)

If you only have a single artifact in your release, you can skip tasks on the job level by using the `Build.SourceBranchName` [release variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=batch#primary-artifact-variables):

[image]

When the variable expression resolves, if the `Build.SourceBranchName` variable is equal to `merge` it skips all following tasks:

[image]

---

## Release variables and custom conditions (multiple artifacts)

Finally, if you're using multiple artifacts in your release, you can still accomplish the above behavior, albeit, you need to do some extra work with a PowerShell script.

You use a PowerShell script to look at the `RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS` environment variable and then looks at the corresponding `RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_<RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS>_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` variable.

Your environment variables (visible in the `Initialize Job` step of a release look like the following.

```
...
[RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_PROJECT1_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]
...
[RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_PROJECT2_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [merge]
...
[RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_PROJECT3_SOURCEBRANCHNAME] --> [master]
...
[RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS] --> [PROJECT2]
...
```

This is also visible in a standard release view.

[image]

[image]

Ultimately we want to see if the triggering artifact's source branch name variable is set to `merge`, if so I short-circuit the release and skip all following tasks via `Control Options Custom conditions`. This is not an ideal situation as Pull Request builds still trigger unnecessary releases, however, it prevents any actual release action from occurring.

### PowerShell task

Below is the PowerShell I'm currently using in the very first task

```
# Use the triggering artifact alias and constructing the name of the variable that will ultimately get us the source branch that triggered the release
$SrcBranchName = "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_$(('$(RELEASE.TRIGGERINGARTIFACT.ALIAS)' -replace '(^\s+|\s+$)','' -replace '\s+','_').ToUpper())_SOURCEBRANCHNAME"

# Get the environment variable that holds the name of the source branch
$SrcBranchName = Get-Item  env:$SrcBranchName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value
Write-Host "SrcBranchName: $SrcBranchName"

if ($SrcBranchName -eq "merge") {
    Write-Host "Release caused by a PR - no further steps will run."
}

# Set an environment variable with the source branch name for use in a Custom Conditions Control
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TriggeringArtifactSourceBranchName;]$SrcBranchName"
```

### Custom Condition

Then for my custom conditions in each task, I use the following which skips the task if the `TriggeringArtifactSourceBranchName` is set to `merge`.

```
and(succeeded(), ne(variables['TriggeringArtifactSourceBranchName'], 'merge'))
```

Comment: So a few notes - we've gone down the path of multiple builds before.  It definitely can solve the problem but with as many builds as we have, it becomes unwieldy to manage.

The branch filters I thought would be a perfect solution, however, we often manually build from feature branches and we want those builds to get picked up by continuous deployment too.

Lastly, removing continuous deployment would indeed do the trick but it's super convenient and i'd hat to throw it to the curb : (

Comment: @StevenZamborsky You can use the Build.SourceBranchName variable to find a source brach and then skip process on the agent job level (not on each task). I`ve updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the followup!  This (to me) seems like the best answer as long as you don't have more than 1 artifact in a release.  When you add multiple (which is our scenario unfortunately) you need to do some rigmarole with the `RELEASE_TRIGGERINGARTIFACT_ALIAS` to figure out which actually triggered the release because I believe the `BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME` is only relevant for the `RELEASE_PRIMARYARTIFACTSOURCEALIAS`.  I'm going to update your answer with my solution for this scenario and accept yoru answer.